# Does the value of destroyed property have a gameplay effect?

Tags: ghostbusters-the-video-game

The value of destroyed property is briefly shown on the upper-left corner of the screen, for example 500$ after tearing a sofa. Is there any reason to avoid destruction, do I for example have to reimburse out of my own pocket?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: IIRC, the only purpose is for getting the achievements that surround the damage dollar amounts

Comment: @Dpeif So no harmful effects? The PC version doesn't have achievements, looks like that causing damage has no impact whatsoever.

Comment: yeah, every [post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/944011-ghostbusters-the-video-game/50019304) i find says its just for the console achievements, and nothing else. kind of a shame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, no.

However, there are achievements / trophies for console versions associated with property damage:

- **Nice Shootin', Tex!** - Complete the game with over $100,000 in property damage
- **The Destructor** - Complete the game with over $3,000,000 in property damage